# django annotation queryset for Sum of datetime

Tags: django, orm, annotations

i have a model below

```
class UserAttemptQuiz(BaseModel):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quiz_user')
     quiz = models.ForeignKey(QuizMcqDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quiz_detail')
     start_time = models.DateTimeField()
     end_time = models.DateTimeField()
     language = models.ForeignKey(QuizLanguage, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     score_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

now i wants to sort the users with their time taken to attempt a quiz so i wrote a code by using annotaion function

```
        day_ranking_obj = UserAttemptQuiz.objects.filter().values('user').annotate(score=Sum("score_count"),time_taken=Sum(
                                  'start_time') - Sum('end_time')).order_by('time_taken')
```

but i am getting an error below:

```
function sum(timestamp with time zone) does not exist\nLINE 1: ...quiz_userattemptquiz\".\"score_count\") AS \"score\", (SUM(\"quiz_...\n                                                             ^\nHINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.\n
```

Comment: What would the sum of a `DateTimeField` even be?? do you want to sum the _difference_ of the two fields? Currently you try to sum the two fields separately and take their difference.

Comment: yes there can be multiple quiz attempt by  a user and i wants to add each end_date and start_date and sort by time taken by user

Comment: What do you expect to get by summing datetimes (let's just take the date part here then what do you expect an operation like `(2021-05-11) + (2021-05-12)` to give you)? Perhaps as I mention again you want to sum the difference of the datetimes?

Comment: i thing you are right is there any another way to achieve this